# HTTP proxy servlet is so slow

Tags: python, http, servlets, proxy, jetty

Let me describe my working env first. I am a university students. My lab has four machines, A, B, C and D connected by 1Gb/s Ethernet. I have a clustering system which uses B and C as computing slaves. This clustering computing system has a Python HTTP server running on machine A. I want to expose this Python HTTP server to other people outside of campus. The good thing is my lab has already set up a Jetty server running on machine D. This jetty server can be reached outside of campus. So I set up a HTTP proxy servlet on machine A. I use this one downloaded from http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/httpproxy.htm. Any request goes to this servlet will be directed to my Python service.

Now, the question is I find the proxy servlet is quite slow. Usually the actual processing time on machine B (clustering computing) is just 0.5 seconds but the result need 5 seconds to be responded and displayed on my browser.

Why is that? Does anybody face slow HTTP proxy situation before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems pretty slow, and my first thought is, what is that servlet doing? Do you have the source?

Next thought is that Jetty apparently provides a [ProxyServlet](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/ProxyServlet.html) of their own. Perhaps they did a better job. Maybe you should try that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You say that machine A has a "Python HTTP server". Is it a handler based on BaseHTTPServer? It can handle only one request at a time:  so do rule out any **waiting problems**.

I guess you are using the same server both to accept jobs from outside and delegate them to B and C over HTTP protocol.

---

To diagnose the paths

1. Outside to D
2. D to A- the proxy D forwards to A
3. A to B- A delegates the work to B

Sync the outside computer, A and D **perfectly** (with NTP) and note these times:

1. print the time on the outside computer immediately before and after requesting to D
2. from the Jetty access logs of D, note the time of your request
3. print the time on A as soon as A preforms do_get()
4. print the time on A after A receives results from B

Do post the delays from #1, #2-#3 and #3-#4 to better diagnose where the delay occurs.